# jquerymobile site demo for desktop browser (issue with body height )

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to show to customer how jquerymobile site will look like. But i'd like to demonstrate it in desktop browser. 
 I've applied style to body

```
<body style="position:relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:320px; height:480px;">
```

but height:480px didn't give any effect. 
It's seems that jquerymobile always adjusts page height according to viewport height
Please advise how fit jquerymobile to 480 height 
thanks

Comment: Just use a good browser like Chrome that enables you to not only spoof your UA so websites think you're a mobile device but you can also spoof your view-port dimensions so you see the site as the mobile device does. In Chrome you find this by opening the developer tooks (F12), then clicking on the Gear Cog at the bottom right that opens the options. Next cick on the "User Agent" tab (top-left) and notice the "Override User Agent" and "Override device metrics" options. This menu also lets you emulate touch events. Note that to use some of these settings you must keep the developer tools open.

Comment: thank you for advice, @Jasper. but i need to fix it permanently. so that anybody from any desktop browser could see 320/480 so to speak emulation of smart phone at web page and jquery mobile site in there

Comment: You can use an `<iframe>` but older devices won't be able to scroll the page.

Comment: @Jasper, `<iframe>` seems to be not bad idea. i'll take a look closely and let know. btw only Firefox 14.0.1 among the latest Opera, Safari, Chrome displays jquery mobile animation on pc correctly

Answer (score 0):

Why not just resize the browser window? Jquery mobile (if you're using it correctly) will display correctly if you shrink the width and height of the browser window (i.e. Safari) to your desired height and width. I feel like what you're trying to implement this the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I use a little Windows app called [Sizer by Brian Apps](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/) which lets me quickly resize a window to exact dimensions by right-clicking on the title bar. I have resolutions for iPhone and iPad, as well as common resolutions for laptops, so I can quickly preview web sites in these areas.

Of course, this is not 100% accurate since it does not take into account the different DPI of each device, but there are more comprehensive (and expensive) simulators exist if you need to do that.